# DbContext in another layer compared to the Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Currently learning how to implement a DDD project in .NET core MVC, and i am running into a problem while trying to create the Db Table with efcore.
Basically what i have is the following:
I have 3 layers, Domain + Application + Infrastructure
and my entities are in the Domain layer, but my DbContext file is in my Domain layer

The problem starts when i try to run the command `add-migration` and it gives me the following error:

```
no dbcontext was found in assembly 'project.domain'. ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.
```

ps: My Domain layer is referenced both in Application layer and Infrastructure layer, because im following once again, the DDD.

Here is My DbContext file:

```
using Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Infrastructure.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here is my Entity File:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Domain.Entities
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ProductPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then, to reference DbContext in `Startup.cs`, i created this extension method:

```
using Infrastructure.Context;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project.Infrastructure
{
    public static class InfrastructureDependencies
    {

        public static void AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services) 
        {
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IApplicationDbContext), typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options 
                => options.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=Domain_Layers\ProductDb"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the top of packet manager console, change project to Infrastructure and run the migration again.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried that, now saying that my Application layer, doesnt reference NuGet EntityFramework.Design, should i install it? wont that take away the point of DDD?

Comment: Now, after creating the propper references, and installing the NuGet entityframework.Design, i got this error while running the migration `Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728`

Comment: Ok, i got it fixed!
For anyone in the future trying to do this, the method of creating the extension method in the Infrastructure Layer, could be a correct option.
So what i did to fix was added in the Application layer references to the Domain layer and Infrastructure layer, after that installed in the Application layer, Entityframework.Design + EntityFramework.Core and ran the command `add-migration + migrationname` on the NuGet package manager Console.
You should have the packet manager referencing the Infrastructure layer, since the DbContext is there

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it fixed! For anyone in the future trying to do this, the method of creating the extension method in the Infrastructure Layer, could be a correct option. So what i did to fix was added in the Application layer references to the Domain layer and Infrastructure layer, after that installed in the Application layer, Entityframework.Design + EntityFramework.Core and ran the command `add-migration` + migrationname on the NuGet package manager Console. You should have the packet manager referencing the Infrastructure layer, since the DbContext is there